# How can I determine which files have been saved on Ubuntu One by Déjà Dup?

Tags: ubuntu-one, backup, deja-dup

I decided to try out the Ubuntu `Backup` system application on my 11.10 partition. Currently I am just using the default settings to back up folders in my Home (~) folder to the `deja-dup` folder (?) in my Ubuntu One cloud.

I have not been able to figure out how to view which files have been saved to the backup location other than by restoring them to a temp folder and then seeing what was restored.

I'm hoping there is a less kludgy way to just find out what has or has not been backed up.